# Check for a pending map redraw

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

Is there a way to detect a pending map redraw? For example

```
map.getView.setCenter([x, y])
```

will not cause a map redraw if x and y are the same as current center, but will cause a redraw if they are different than the current view center. (At least that seems to be what I'm seeing, please correct me if I'm mistaken).

So I want to check the map to see if a redraw will happen. Obviously in this simple example I could test the x,y values for myself, but I have several similar things that I'm doing so it would be cleaner if I could just check the map once at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what I want. I still feel like there should be a better way

```
var pendingRedraw = false;
var movestartHandler = map.on('movestart',  function(evt)  {
    pendingRedraw = true;
});
/*
    code that may, or may not, trigger a map redraw
*/
unByKey(movestartHandler);  // un-register the handler
if (pendingRedraw) {
    // now I know what I want to know! 
}
```